# Probability of drawing all "socks" of a given color from a drawer, given certain number of tries

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Let's talk "socks."

Say I have 7800 socks in a drawer (it's a big drawer), 800 of which are red and 7000 of which are black.

If I randomly pull 1300 socks from the drawer, what is the probability that I will draw EVERY ONE of the 800 red socks?

I realize there are a number of similar threads, and apologize if this is repetitive -- I have searched and failed to find a situation sufficiently similar to allow me to work through this on my own.

Many thanks for any assistance!

Answer (score 3):

For an "exact" answer, note that there are $\binom{7800}{1300}$ ways to choose the socks, all equally likely.

There are $\binom{800}{800}\binom{7000}{500}$ ways to choose all the reds and $500$ of the black. Divide.

The "practical" answer is that the probability is virtually $0$.

**Remark:** Wolfram Alpha gives that the probability is a bit under $1.5\times 10^{-744}$. Small indeed. One is more likely to win the grand prize in the lottery $80$ weeks in a row.

One can also compute by hand. Ue the fact that $\binom{n}{r}=\frac{n(n-1)\cdots(n-r+1)}{r!}$. We find that the probability is
$$\frac{(1300)(1299)\cdots (801)}{(7800)(7999)\cdots (7001)}.$$
Note that the ratio of the first two corresponding terms, $1300$ and $7800$, is $\frac{1}{6}$, and then decreases. So our probability is less than $(1/6)^{800}$. To put it in terms of dice, our probability is less than the probability of tossing a fair die $800$ times and getting a $6$ each time.

Comment: this assumes all socks of a colour to be unique

Comment: No it doesn't. It assumes that the $\binom{7800}{1300}$ possible choices are equally likely, which is the most reasonable interpretation of "randomly pull."

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. Is there a way to simplify or approximate this calculation (I can't find a binomial coefficient calculator that can handle numbers that large)? I understand that the answer is practically zero, but I made a friendly bet with someone that it was less than 0.1% -- in order to win, I need to produce something more specific. Thank you again, very much, for your response.

Comment: You are welcome. It is easiest to turn to Wolfram Alpha. It says that the number is less than $1.5\times 10^{-744}$. Just type in binom(7000,500)/binom(7800,1300). One could also do a make a back of the envelope calculation that would quickly show the number is very very small.

Comment: A little simplification of the binomial coefficients gets us that the answer is $\frac{(1300)(1299)\cdots(801)}{(7800)(7999)\cdots(7001)}$. There are $800$ terms on top and bottom. The ratio of corresponding terms is never bigger than $\frac{1}{6}$. So the ratio is less than $(1/6)^{800}$. You only need $(1/6)^4$ to get below your bet target.